# Coupled with the slow performance , Taskbar is not showing up in Windows 11

Tags: windows, taskbar

I hope you guys are all well. So I am in a strange predicament. In my Windows 11 , which I upgraded from Windows 10 a couple of months ago, Strange issues I am facing day by day.

1. My system takes long time to settle down and what I mean by that is that , It does get reboot very quickly but it takes time before I am able to click on some icons on desktop.
2. I am not been able to delete any file or folder on my desktop instantly, First it tells me that the file does not exist but when I refresh the desktop then the file or folder gets deleted.
3. Earlier it used to take like 10 to 15 minutes before I was able to view my windows status and task bar but now from couple of days it has got complelety blank.

What could be the probable issue for above problems? Windows has gotten corrupted, System has gotten slow , Is there some malware in the system? Should I reinstall windows again or is there some solution for these issues.

[image]

Regards
Looking forward from your kind reply.

Comment: Best solution is to back up important data and them do a clean install of W11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An upgrade from Windows 10 can (and does) go wrong.

Two things you can try:

**(1) Windows 11 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

(If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.)

**(2) If Repair with Keep Everything does not work,**

then back up and install Windows 11 Fresh.

Comment: John thats really helpful. Thanks a lot.